# Laravel Time value getting wrong according to real time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, time, timezone

i developed the function to get current date and time value.it works fine.but time value is wrong.now time is 12.32 pm in my time but it save in the database as 6.40am.

Here is the controller function um using.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request['time']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", time());
    attendance::create($request->all());
            return view('traineeattendance.attendanceo');
}
```

**Sri Lanka Standard Time (SLST) is the time zone for Sri Lanka. It is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of GMT/UTC (UTC+05:30)
so that Time Zone = GMT+5.5.**

can anyone help me to figure out this?

Comment: Use Carbon Date Time

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how 12:32 PM gets changed to 06:40 AM . There's no logical conversion that will make a X:32 minute time into Y:40 minute time.

Comment: Do you mind printing the full datetime+tz in `$request["time"]` and the full datetime+tz that gets saved to the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `config/app.php` you will find a `timezone` setting

by default its `UTC`

you need to change that according to your timezone

like

```
timezone = 'Asia/Colombo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$time = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Colombo'));
```

Comment: um not using carbon functions to get time bro

Comment: @Dasun You should. It's already included with laravel and laravel uses Carbon in eloquent models by default.

Comment: It has alot of inbuilt functions so that you can change and format times so easily